# How to refer to a module (and construct the names of its contents) in template haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I have a splice I'm writing in TH which needs to take a list of module names and create new names based on a convention I have for these modules. At the moment I am doing this by passing in `String`s of the module names, but I'm not thrilled by this and it seems like there should be a name to refer to the module more ... programmatically.

This is the splice:

```hs
link ::
  String ->
  [String] ->
  Name ->
  Q [Dec]
link prefix features monadName = do
  let routeName = mkName $ capitalise prefix <> "Routes"
      handlerName = mkName $ lowerFirst prefix <> "Handler"
  routes <- mkRoutes routeName ((<> ".Routes") <$> features)
  handler <- mkHandler handlerName routeName monadName ((<> ".routeHandler") <$> features)
  pure $ routes : handler
```

So, as you can see, it basically adds `.Routes` and `.routeHandler` onto the module names, and then passes those into other functions to construct the actual declarations (I'm generating Servant `ServerT` declarations).

Is there a way to refer to the module itself and then to construct new names from it? Something like:

```hs
import Project.Feature.MyCoolFeature qualified as MyCoolFeature

-- ...
-- this doesn't work, but it's the sort of thing I want:
moduleName :: Name
moduleName = ''MyCoolFeature
memberName :: Name
memberName = moduleName <.> mkName "Routes"
```